# SimpleAdapter Filter

Tags: android

Hi I have and issue when I filter data on the simple adapter crash my app and exit I can not catch the error even in a try the very unexpected is I have another activity exact the same format just with another query and its works fine these is very rare here is my code if someone can help me very thanks in advance

```
        final SimpleAdapter cxcada = new SimpleAdapter(ListadoCXCActivity.this, cxclist, R.layout.cxclista, from, to);
        lvcxc.setAdapter(cxcada);

        //Search
        buscarcxc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            //here crash my app and exit without any log         
            cxcada.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        });
```

Comment: Add your logcat with the stacktrace.

Comment: You can check the error by checking logcat. When an app crashes and exits then it is not shown in logcat because it shows you only the running app. However, you can filter that in logcat and in that way you can see the "DEAD" app's error. Please do so and then copy paste the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter don't work if the adapter has any null to prevent must validate don't load any null in the adapter, I fix from the query before to load the data with

```
isnull(Column_Name, 'Default') as Column_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a error before when I use TextWatcher. Because I changed the words in EditText when `onTextChanged` was invoked.

So, did you do that like me? Did `cxcada.getFilter().filter(cs);` change your EditText content?

Comment: Yes these trigger when I start to write the first character of any letter or number,  I debug and the CharSequence is not null and the adapter has rows to, the load its ok because first I fill the ListView these error happen when I try to filter the data